# jQuery bring image to front not working

Tags: jquery, image, z-index

I am attempting, on click, to bring an image to the front (via z-index) and increase the size of the clicked image. My code doesn't appear to be working. Can someone please suggest an edit to get it working?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="click-to-top first"><img src="img/cherry.png" alt="Cherry"  class="cherry" /></div>
<div class="click-to-top"><img src="img/lemon.png" alt="Lemon" class="lemon" /></div>
<div class="click-to-top last"><img src="img/apple.png" alt="Apple" class="apple" /></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.click-to-top').click(function(){
var topZ = 0;
$('.click-to-top').each(function(){
    var thisZ = parseInt($(this).css('z-index'), 10);
    if (thisZ > topZ){
        topZ = thisZ;
    }
});
$(this).css('z-index', topZ+3);
});
```

*CSS*

```
.container{
max-width:600px;
margin:0 auto;
}

div.click-to-top {
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
max-width:160px;
}

div.click-to-top.last,div.click-to-top.first{
z-index:-1;
}

div.click-to-top img{
max-width:160px;
margin:0 30px;
}
```

Comment: Why have you given `z-index:-1;` to `div.click-to-top.last` and `div.click-to-top.first`. The event for them is not getting triggered. Here is a **[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/h4dngkt5/1/)** to check when `z-index=1` for the above

Comment: The images overlap and so I wanted to ensure the middle image was on top as default. Is there anyway I can also expand the image on click Guruprasad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looking which image has the highest Z-index, why not reset all z-indexes (indices?) and only change the one of the image being clicked?

```
$('.click-to-top').click(function(){

    $('.click-to-top').css('z-index', 1);
    $(this).css('z-index', 2);
});
```